# JBoss 6 Heap Size goes out of memory

Tags: memory, jboss, heap-memory

On startup of `Jboss EAP 6 server`, because of static caching the heap size increases to more than `4096M` while same application hosted on `Jboss 5 GA` heap size does not exceed `2000M`.

I am using following VM arguments to boot the server.

`-server -Xms1024M -Xmx4096M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000`

Is there a different GC strategy involved in getting Jboss 6 Heap 6 increase.

Thanks

Comment: you can have a lot of unecessary JBoss module started in standard that you will never use and that grow the HEAP. But do you have OutOfMemoryError again ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the GC algorithm using jmap -heap   of the JVM. But it does not make sense, memory utilization is purely based on the application requirement. If you had 2GB of heap in your previous JBoss version, certainly with same load, and other VM arguments then either your infrastructure would have deployed an limiting factor ( for example thread pool configuration) or your application would have given OOME.

"Is there a different GC strategy involved in getting Jboss 6 Heap 6 increase."

To add a note on above line, JBoss does not decide what GC algorithm should be adopted for your application. Its the Java (JRE) who decides (until and unless you direct it to particular configuration). Java decides based on the server, OS configuration.

JBoss will only comes with default min and max heap and perm size .. rest is all dependent on the Java you are using.